# Getting 5 or 7 and returning the opposite?

Tags: algorithms, puzzle, transformation

I get 5 or 7 and if i get 5 i need to return 7 if i get 7 i need to return 5.

i need to do this in 1 mathematical formula.

I have those:

```
12 - x

35 / x
```

There are more solutions ?

Example in code:

```
public static int Transform(int x)
{
    return (12-x);
    //return (35/x);
}
```

Comment: There are infinitely many more...

Comment: Can you show me some ?
But smart ones not like `13-x-1`

Comment: Example: $\sqrt{74 - x^2}$. This can be easily generalized.

Comment: I am voting to close as NARQ.

Comment: Why are you unsatisfied with the simple ones you already have?

Comment: It's a Puzzle..

Comment: @Danpe, this isn't a puzzle site.

Comment: This is the same as finding how many functions in the Cartesian plan go through the points $(5,7)$ and $(7,5)$... which is indeed infinite.

Comment: If $h$ is an invertible function we can define $f(x) = h^{-1}(h(5) + h(7) - h(x))$.  This $f$ has the property that you want.  This covers the two methods you have (with $h(x)=x$ and $h(x)=\log(x)$, respectively, and quite a few more.

Comment: $f(x) = 12 - x + (x-5)(x-7)h(x)$ or $f(x) = 35/ x + (x-5)(x-7)h(x)$ etc

Comment: You can also multiply any formula you've found by (x-6)^2, of course.

Answer (score 5):

return x ^ 2;

Are you sure you aren't missing any constraints?

Comment: This doesn't return 5 when x is 7...nor does it return 7 when x is 5

Comment: He was using Java or C++ in his original question; ^ is a bitwise XOR.

A test confirms that x^2 swaps both 5 and 7 in Visual C++ 10.0.

Comment: A way to verify this answer: $2 = 5\ \text{XOR}\ 7$. (So basically `return x ^ (5 ^ 7);`)

Comment: Woops, my bad. I was naively thinking exponentiation.

Comment: yeah, I read it as exponentiation, too. You might want to make it clear in the answer that it is a bitwise operator.  (Mathematicians tend to not think of bitwise operators as "mathematical formulas" as a rule.)

Comment: Since this isn't SO, a "where `^` is bitwise XOR" would have went a long way. :)